# Wave Packet Fourier Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, fft, physics, waveform

I am looking to create a program in Java that can use symbolic, as well as numerical, data in a Fourier Transform in order to combine various sinusoidal wave functions into a single wave packet, i.e. changing a position wave function into a momentum wave function and vice-versa. I have tried using algorithms like the [Princeton](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html) one found here, but the input isn't quite broad enough as I would like to use functions of the form e^ikx in variables as well as actual sine graph.

Are there any suggestions as to a Java system library that I could download, or a method I could implement in order to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this tool.

http://www.fftw.org/index.html

It has a couple different options for Java wrappers.  I too tried using the Princeton algorithm a few years ago and found that it didn't meet my needs.

I'm not enough of a DSP expert to know for sure if FFTW will meet your needs but it looks like a robust option.

Comment: I think this should work, but I am actually quite a programming novice. Are there any resources you recommend for learning how to use Java wrappers, or can you point me to where in the C library I should look? Thanks.

Comment: @B.Klein if you go to the downloads page and download the zip file "Java wrappers for FFTW," you can peruse the documentation. You won't have to do anything with C yourself. 
 http://www.fftw.org/download.html